# Jekyll: how a draft refer to another draft

Tags: jekyll

I am writing a draft in _drafts/ directory.

```
   _drafts/
          draft_a.md
          draft_b.md
```

What is the syntax of referring to draft_b inside draft_a.md?

I tried post_url, or just simply /draft_b.md.  None of those worked.

Comment: I think it's not possible. They are not going to be in the `site.posts`, so `post_url` is not accesible. But If you move them to posts and add the unpublished property: `published: false` in your http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/, you can link them and see them if you run locally the `--unpublished` flag ;)

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

1. Use jekyll serve with `--drafts` to make them accessible

   ```
   jekyll serve --drafts
   ```
2. In one draft use the tag `link` to refer to the other draft. Suppose you have two drafts:

   ```
    /_drafts/one.md
    /_drafts/two.md
   ```

In `one.md`:

```
      {{ site.baseurl }}{% link _drafts/two.md %}
```

Then when accessing the served `one.md` it will contain a link to the other post `/two`.